# Spring Boot @Autowire HazelcastInstance without XML or YAML

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm trying to run Hazelcast client application with Spring Boot without XML/YAML file but I can't find a way to manage my Hazelcast instance via Spring. This is my code

```java
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ClientConfig clientConfig() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = clientConfig.getNetworkConfig();
        networkConfig.addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701").setSmartRouting(true).addOutboundPortDefinition("34700-34710").setRedoOperation(true).setConnectionTimeout(5000);

        return clientConfig;

    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }
}
```

And when I try to Autowire Hazelcast instance into main class I get `NULL`. Main class code

```java
public class HazelcastServer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798311083790835361L;

    @Autowired
    private static HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("hazelcastInstance: " + hazelcastInstance);
 }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse it is `null`. First `@Autowired` doesn't work on `static` fields, second you aren't even using the configuration you've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `CommandLineRunner` so that Spring builds your context (in other words, creates your `@Bean`s and autowires them)

See the tutorial here for a good start:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Basically, instead of the `public static void main` you need to do something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

The `@SpringBootApplication` and `SpringApplication.run` part tells Spring to do it's magic, read the tutorial I linked for the details.

Comment: You can use the bean perfectly fine without a `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: Which is not what your answer suggests.

Comment: They want to print an autowired object as the only line in the main method of a console app. I think my recommendation is appropriate for that. I'm not writing them a book on how to use spring, just answering the question.

Comment: `SpringApplication.run` delivers an `ApplicationContext` which you can just use to get the bean. You can achieve the same with 3 lines of code. But still your answer says that they **should use** a `CommandLineRunner` not that they **could use** a `CommandLineRunner`. It is just 1 letter that is different but that makes the answer a better one.